# Apex Websocket server

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

Is there way to connect to apex code with wss (websocket) protocol?

I successfully connected to an external url from Salesforce client  component, but I am wondering if there is a way to create a websocket **server** in Salesforce and connect to it from a client component.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apex only supports HTTP/1 from early 2000's . WebSocket server or GRPC(HTTP/2) are bi-directional and quite latest mid/late 2010's. So natively in Salesforce Apex you cant achieve this.

Client Component you can do that using [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications), as its websocket API isnative to JS. You have to stick with aura/lwc component.

You can raise an idea for its support in apex [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch).

Comment: There is an idea already: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DxSQAA0